# ERROR TypeError: "this.ngChatInstance is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

i am getting ERROR TypeError: "this.ngChatInstance is undefined" when i am clicking 'chat from navbar' no error is coming but when clicking 'chat from page' then i got error.

i am using [ng-chat](https://github.com/rpaschoal/ng-chat)

navbar.component.html

```
<p> navbar works!</p>
<a (click)="clickchat()">Chat from navbar</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a (click)="clickchatclose()">close from navbar</a>
<ng-chat #ngChatInstance [adapter]="adapter" [userId]="999" [historyEnabled]="true" [historyPageSize]="4" [hideFriendsList]="false" (onMessagesSeen)="messageSeen($event)"></ng-chat>
```

navbar.componenet.ts

```
import { ChatAdapter,IChatController,UserStatus } from 'ng-chat'; 
import { DemoAdapter } from './demo-adapter';

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('ngChatInstance')
protected ngChatInstance: IChatController;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

public adapter: ChatAdapter = new DemoAdapter();

public messageSeen(event: any)
{
  console.log(event);
}

public clickchat(){
  let user:any = {
  id: 2,
  displayName: "Cersei Lannister",
avatar: null,
status: UserStatus.Online
};
  console.log(user);
  console.log(this.ngChatInstance);
this.ngChatInstance.triggerOpenChatWindow(user);
}

public clickchatclose(){
this.ngChatInstance.triggerCloseChatWindow(2);
 }
 }
```

page.componenet.ts

```
import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';

export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('ngChatInstance')
protected ngChatInstance: IChatController;

constructor(
  public navbar: NavbarComponent
) { }

ngOnInit() {
}
clickchatformpage(){
this.navbar.clickchat();

}

clickchatcloseformpage(){

}
}
```

page.componenet.html

```
<p>
 page works!
</p>
<a (click)="clickchatformpage()">Chat from page</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a (click)="clickchatcloseformpage()">close from page</a>
```

see example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht1lgt)

thanks.

Comment: In `page.component.ts` you can remove
`@ViewChild('ngChatInstance') protected ngChatInstance: IChatController;`
since the chat is not part of the `page.component.html` template.
Invoking `this.navbar.clickchat();` from `page.component.ts` should work, however.
What is the output of `console.log(this.ngChatInstance);`?

Comment: yes i removed     @ViewChild('ngChatInstance') protected ngChatInstance: IChatController;

Comment: how do you get the reference to `navbar` in `PageComponent`? if it is in the parent you could inject it with `constructor(
  @Inject(NavbarComponent) public navbar: NavbarComponent
)`

Comment: that is not parent, parent is app.component

Comment: when click from navbar `console.log(this.ngChatInstance);` it show in console `NgChat {sanitizer: DomSanitizerImpl, _httpClient: HttpClient, UserStatus: {…}, MessageType: {…}, isCollapsed: true, …}` but when click from page it show in console `undefined`

Comment: You need to get a reference to the navbar component. Which template contains the navbar component? it would be helpful if you could show an example on [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: this is example [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht1lgt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht1lgt)

if you didn't see changes please increase output window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to `navbar` inside of `page.component.ts`
One way to achieve this is to get a reference of navbar inside the app component

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(NavbarComponent) public navbar: NavbarComponent;
}
```

Then you inject the app component in the constructor of the page component and use the reference to navbar of the app component:

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(AppComponent) private appComponent: AppComponent
  ) { }

  clickchatformpage(){
    this.appComponent.navbar.clickchat();
  }
```

Here is a modified version of your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hceet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks,
this is working but is there another way without using app.component?

Comment: @MukeshKumar another possibility would be to have an `@Input() navbar: NavbarComponent` in `page.component.ts` instead of the injected value and then in `app.component.ts` you can pass the navbar reference `<app-navbar #navbar></app-navbar>
<app-page [navbar]="navbar"></app-page>`.
See this modified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f792xm?file=src/app/page/page.component.ts